# How to draw the complex region?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

My region is:

For $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\theta\in (0,\pi/2)$ let $\Lambda=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}: \theta\leq |arg(\lambda-a)|\leq \pi \}$. So, i do not know if i need to work with
$\theta\leq |arg(\lambda-a)|$ which is equivalent to $arg(\lambda-a)>\theta$ union with the region $arg(\lambda-a)<-\theta$ and this region will do intersection with the other region
$-\pi<arg(\lambda-a)<\pi$. Is very confuse for me. Please can get any hint?

I know that it is not a bounded region because we do not have conditions as for example $|\lambda-a|\leq R$.

Thank you